# Java.net(RestFul service JSON reponse parsing issue) How to convert list of same item in JSON reponse String to Java Object?

Tags: java

I am calling Restful service using below code :(Java.net implementation )

```
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try 
{
    URL url = new URL(restUrl);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod(httpRequestMethod);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    if (requestHeaders != null) 
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :  requestHeaders.entrySet()) 
        {
            conn.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {//do something}
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
       responseStrBuilder.append(output);
```

Approach 1: 
I have below string(JSON String) as my Restful service response , how can I convert it to Java object. Since same(Itm) object is repeated multiple times if I use `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject myObject = new org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());` 
It only reads first Itm Object and does not bring list of all item object.

JSON String output from service :

```
{"Response":{"RID":"04'34'",
"Itm":{"id":{"ab":"1","cd":"12"},"qw":"JK","name":"abcd "},
"Itm":{"id":{"ab":"2","cd":"34},"qw":"JK","name":"asdf "},
"Itm":{"id":{"ab":"3","cd":"12"},"qw":"JK","name":"fghj "}
}}
```

Approach 2: 
I also tried below snippet with correct Java object with setters and getters

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MyJavaReponseObject javaObj = mapper.readValue(json, MyJavaReponseObject.class);
```

This approach also reads only one object of Itm and not all the object as its not coming in array format in JSON string. Is there any better way of getting all the object(Itm) mapped to single List of Object in java pojo ?

Comment: Your json seems to be invalid (pasted into https://jsonlint.com/ and it fails to validate). Furthermore, in that response, I don't see an array represented anywhere (e.g. [{}) ]so it seems your json response is just an object containing other objects so model your POJO accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the List class in your response object, if you should parse that json string itself.

I have a ReponseJSON class with json objects, one Response and three Itms

```
static class ReponseJSON {
    private Response Response;

    @JsonProperty("Response")
    public Response getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response Response) {
        this.Response = Response;
    }

    static class Response {
        private String rid;
        private Itm Itm;
        private List<Itm> listItm = new ArrayList<Itm>();

        public Itm getItm() {
            return Itm;
        }

        @JsonProperty("Itm")
        public void setItm(Itm Itm) {
            this.Itm = Itm;
            listItm.add(Itm);
        }

        public String getRID() {
            return rid;
        }

        public List<Itm> getItms() {
            return listItm;
        }

        @JsonProperty("RID")
        public void setRID(String rid) {
            this.rid = rid;
        }

        static class Itm {
            private Id id;

            private String qw, name;

            public String getQw() {
                return qw;
            }

            public void setQw(String qw) {
                this.qw = qw;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Id getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Id id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            static class Id {
                private String ab, cd;

                public String getCd() {
                    return cd;
                }

                public void setCd(String cd) {
                    this.cd = cd;
                }

                public String getAb() {
                    return ab;
                }

                public void setAb(String ab) {
                    this.ab = ab;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a Response class, I have a list class and save a Itm object whenever object mapper call this class.

```
static class Response {
    ... skip ..
    private List<Itm> listItm = new ArrayList<Itm>();
    ... skip ..
    @JsonProperty("Itm")
    public void setItm(Itm Itm) {
        this.Itm = Itm;
        listItm.add(Itm);
    }
}
```

Check the full source code as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonParserTest {

    static class ReponseJSON {
        private Response Response;

        @JsonProperty("Response")
        public Response getResponse() {
            return Response;
        }

        public void setResponse(Response Response) {
            this.Response = Response;
        }

        static class Response {
            private String rid;
            private Itm Itm;
            private List<Itm> listItm = new ArrayList<Itm>();

            public Itm getItm() {
                return Itm;
            }

            @JsonProperty("Itm")
            public void setItm(Itm Itm) {
                this.Itm = Itm;
                listItm.add(Itm);
            }

            public String getRID() {
                return rid;
            }

            public List<Itm> getItms() {
                return listItm;
            }

            @JsonProperty("RID")
            public void setRID(String rid) {
                this.rid = rid;
            }

            static class Itm {
                private Id id;

                private String qw, name;

                public String getQw() {
                    return qw;
                }

                public void setQw(String qw) {
                    this.qw = qw;
                }

                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }

                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }

                public Id getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(Id id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                static class Id {
                    private String ab, cd;

                    public String getCd() {
                        return cd;
                    }

                    public void setCd(String cd) {
                        this.cd = cd;
                    }

                    public String getAb() {
                        return ab;
                    }

                    public void setAb(String ab) {
                        this.ab = ab;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String responseJson = 
        "{\"Response\":{\"RID\":\"04'34'\","
                + "\"Itm\":{\"id\":{\"ab\":\"1\",\"cd\":\"12\"},\"qw\":\"JK\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}"
                + ",\"Itm\":{\"id\":{\"ab\":\"2\",\"cd\":\"34\"},\"qw\":\"JK\",\"name\":\"asdf\"}"
                + ",\"Itm\":{\"id\":{\"ab\":\"3\",\"cd\":\"12\"},\"qw\":\"JK\",\"name\":\"fghj\"}"
                + "}} ";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ReponseJSON responseObj = null;

        try {
            responseObj = mapper.readValue(responseJson, ReponseJSON.class);
            ReponseJSON.Response response = responseObj.getResponse();

            for(int i = 0; i < response.getItms().size(); i++)
            {
                ReponseJSON.Response.Itm item = response.getItms().get(i);

                System.out.println(item.getId().getAb());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The version of my jackson mapper is 2.9.1.

You check the main method of the source, because the JSON string you prepared is invalid as coddemonkey mentioned.

[image]

Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you for such a unique solution. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Make your json response looks something similar to this

```
{"Response":{"RID":"04'34'",
"Itms":[{"id":{"ab":"1","cd":"12"},"qw":"JK","name":"abcd "},
{"id":{"ab":"2","cd":"34"},"qw":"JK","name":"asdf "},
{"id":{"ab":"3","cd":"12"},"qw":"JK","name":"fghj "}]
}}
```

then, use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107) jar to parse the string to jsonObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseString);
```

This is one type of solution, if you can't change the response as mentioned above then you have to manually parse the string(using java bean) there is no other option available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can not change JSON .